# htaccess - change URL by modifying one parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have URLs that look like this:

```
page.php?id=1&lan=en
```

I want to change it to `page-1.html?lan=en` via htaccess.
Please note that I have to get the value of both parameters `id` and `lan` too.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use codes below. I didn't try it, but it should work

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page-(\d*).html$ page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```